# Google Chrome: removing hyphenation

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hyphenation

I have an odd problem: I have a Bootstrap 3/Wordpress 3.6.1 site with 3 narrow - ~200px wide - paragraphs of text in the centre and DON'T want hyphenation. In Safari and Firefox it's fine, but in Chrome (Version 30) the text hyphenates automagically. It's not a Wordpress function as I wrote the functions file, and I don't think it's a bootstrap 3 thing, but just to be sure I set *'hyphens'* to *'none'* in the mixins.

I have tried turning it off in CSS with

```
word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: none;
-moz-hyphens: none;
-ms-hyphens: none;
-o-hyphens: none;
hyphens: none;
```

When I search for it I get a lot of pages describing how to *enable* it, but none describing how to *disable* it.

Comment: The syntax you have to turn them off is correct (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fhyphens) Do you happen to have a URL we can look at?

Comment: Do you mean that words are hyphenated, or that they are broken: divided into two lines without a hyphen at the end of a line? The latter would be what you are *asking for* with `word-wrap: break-word` (which should almost never be used for texts in English, for example).

Comment: Jukka - The text is hyphenating with hyphens, but only in chrome. The hyphens don't appear in the page source. David - The url is http://www.lifecoreconsulting.com/

Comment: Chrome still does not support the `hyphens` property. http://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens

Comment: I've never seen a browser add hyphens to words. Please provide a demo.

Comment: Assuming the op means not to add or remove actual hyphens, but the break-on-hyphen option then there are limited options.